# Prompt in cmd when using subprocess in python

Tags: python, subprocess

I have this code:

```
command = "runas /user:theuser cmd"
subprocess.run(command)
```

and here cmd asks for password to theuser
My question is if I can enter the password here using python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `subprocess.Popen` instead. This means you can communicate with the program:

```
command = "runas /user:theuser cmd"
p = Popen([command], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
p.communicate(input='data')[0]
```

You can check out [The docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=popen#popen-constructor) for more info